# Is every subgroup of $S_n$ cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

I've just showed that every subgroup of $S_3$ is cyclic.

I'm not familiar with permutation groups yet and I'm curious to know whether every subgroup of $S_n$ is cyclic.

As a counterexample might be $S_4$ probably, but I'm not sure at all.

Thanks in advance for explanation.

Comment: Is $S_3$ cyclic? Is $S_k$ a subgroup of $S_n$ for $k<n$?

Comment: Good question - you will see from the comments and answers that you can't generalise in this way from small groups to large ones. Every good group theorist began by asking questions like this.

Comment: Every *proper* subgroup: $S_3$ is not cyclic.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/253777

Answer (score 3):

No.

By [Cayley's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20group%20theory%2C%20Cayley%27s%20theorem,on%20the%20elements%20of%20G.&text=(a%20group%20of%20order%20720).), every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group $S_n$ for some $n$ (dependent upon the finite group).

Answer (score 0):

The [Klein subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_Klein_four-subgroup_of_S4) of $S_4$ is a non cyclic proper subgroup of order $4$. All its elements have order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that all proper subgroups of $S_n$ are cyclic, it  would imply that all proper subgroups are abelian. Now  it is quite easy to show that $A_n$ is not abelian for $n\ge 4$.

Answer (score 0):

$S_4$ has subgroups of orders 1,2,3,4,6,8,12 and 24. Except subgroups of orders 1,2 and 3 (these groups are always cyclic) and some subgroups of order 4, all other subgroups are non cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

That is a property that cyclic groups possess.  And while there are examples, such as $S_3$, of non-cyclic groups which possess it also, $S_n, n\gt3$ are not among them.

As already remarked, for instance, $S_k\le S_n\,,\forall k\lt n$.